# PHP mail won't send to my own domain?

Tags: php, email

I'm sending a simple mail message like so

```
mail("info@mydomain.com","foo","bar");
```

The mail is successfully sent and received everywhere, but not if I send it to an email that is set on my own domain.

I redirected the mail to Outlook.com and opened a few accounts there, and they will not receive any messages sent from my site.

The first issue that I can think of is some sort of a loopback problem, but I have no idea how to solve this issue..
I'm on a shared hosting so I don't have too much access either..

Any input might help,
Thanks

Comment: Did you properly configure your domain so it points at outlook.com's smtp servers? Did you tell outlook.com that they're to be receiving mail for that domain?

Comment: Does any other e-mails arrive to your domain mail box?

Comment: @MarcB Yes, I am already receiving mail on my mail boxes, it's working just fine, just the mail I send from my php script won't reach them.

Comment: @matewka Yep, I'm getting other e-mails just fine.

Comment: Then check for things like spam reject, e.g. check your server's maillog and see what happens when the outgoing mail tries to go to outlook's servers.

Comment: @MarcB Do you have any clue how I am supposed to see the mail log? I can see the error_log and the access_log but they don't seem to contain any information about the mail

Comment: assuming you're on a unix-system, it's generally /var/log/maillog or similar.

Comment: @MarcB Looks like I won't be able to view that file then as I'm limited to this "Parallels" control panel. ugh this is getting annoying :I thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem myself in a site.

There was an issue with the way our system was set up, so that the system thought that because the email was coming from the same domain it was a spam email and as such blocked it.

Check with your system administrator that you are allowed to be sending the emails etc.

Either that, or you'll have to modify the headers to have look like it's being sent from an external address. Hope you get it sorted.

Comment: I did have an attempt to modify the headers and add the "From: My Name <info@asdasd.com>" but again, it doesnt get to my inbox.. (When I sent it to other mailboxes with the modified headers I could see the modified address)

Comment: I've similarly run into the described issue before, and recall having to reach out to my webhost to get it resolved.

Comment: take a look here http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-cant-send-emails-to-its-own-domain
and http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-wont-send-emails-to-same-domain